# How can I conceal an over-the-range microwave?

Tags: kitchens, design

We are in the process of remodelling our kitchen, and are going from an electric to gas stove. Because of this, we are going to need a vented range hood.

One thing that we are certain about is that we'd like the microwave oven to be concealed in the kitchen. This can be accomplished by putting it inside a roomy cabinet. What I'd like to do, however, is install an over-the-range microwave, but somehow conceal the thing. eg: install doors in front of it (or something).

Has anyone done this, or have any advice on how I might go about doing it?

Comment: If you hide the OTR microwave you will also be hiding the fan/vent controls since they will be on the microwave control panel.

Comment: Good point. Why can't they make a OTR microwave that doesn't look like the gaudy appliance that it is? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used to be able to buy microwaves that you could apply cabinet facing to, but a quick google search doesn't show any examples.

There are a number of ways to put a cabinet door over a microwave, and it looks like the following would probably suit your needs best:

http://www.houzz.com/hidden-microwave

There is cabinet hardware that lifts the cabinet door out and up, so if properly mounted you can have the bottom venting portion of the microwave open for the stove, and cover the rest of the microwave with the same cabinet facing you have in the kitchen.  You just lift it up to access the microwave.

Comment: These are putting the microwave in a cabinet, but that doesn't work as well for over the range microwaves that include the lights and fan for the range.

Comment: @BMitch Yes, but what I'm talking about is mounting the microwave normally above the range, then adding a cabinet door over it.  The link shows examples of the microwave going into a cabinet, but look at the doors - they can be mounted above or to the side of the microwave even if the microwave is mounted as vent hood.  No need to build the whole cabinet, just use the door hardware to mount a cabinet door over the microwave.

Comment: Oops, sorry, not enough sleep. I should have ready your last paragraph more carefully.

Comment: Thank you for that URL. It's providing me with a lot of ideas (to the point where I am changing my kitchen plans!). Those hinge systems are slick - looks perfect!